# Make Gradle Output have Prefix Tagging like Maven

Tags: gradle

I love Gradle over Maven.  But one thing I do like is the prefix tagging that maven does:

[image]

Is there any way to configure Gradle to have this style of output?

[image]

If I could then I bet I could get my team and maybe company to switch completely over.